# compare and print the values in two arrays using awk

Tags: awk, bioinformatics

```
A01     11814111        11814112        GA      AA
A01     11485477        11485519        AG      AT
A01     11667935        11667971        TC      TA
A01     11876070        11876079        TC      TG
A01     11613258        11613277        AC      GC
A01     11876079        11876107        CA      GA
A01     11616453        11616463        TA      TG
A01     11875367        11875368        GG      GA
A01     11667971        11667993        CA      AA
A01     11564406        11564411        TA      TG
A01     11477215        11477235        TG      CG
```

The awk script to split the values of column 4 and 5 and then test these against each other pairwise. When a value differs between the two arrays, the string from the first column is printed with an underscore and the appropriate value from column 2 or 3. If both nucleotides are different, two lines of output are to be produced. 
Also, print the differed values in col 4 and 5 against each id.

```
awk '{ split($4, a1, ""); split($5, a2, ""); for (i in a1) { if (a1[i] != a2[i]) print $1 "_" $(i+1) }}' input > out
```

does the first part.

output needed as:

```
A01_11814111 G A

A01_11485519 G T
```

Comment: Are you sure the expected output is what will produce for the given input ? So why `A01_11667971   C A` or some other pairs didn't come in output? those are different.

Comment: Looks like all you have to do is `print $1 "_" $(i+1), a1[i], a2[i]`

Comment: and what if both nucleotides are **equal** ?

Comment: If both nucl are equal then should not be printed. should not be case where both nucl are same.

Comment: @Gavin, elaborate how this condition *two lines of output are to be produced* should be outputed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of `tmp.txt`

```
A01     11814111        11814112        GA      AA
A01     11485477        11485519        AG      AT
A01     11667935        11667971        TC      TA
A01     11876070        11876079        TC      TG
A01     11613258        11613277        AC      GC
A01     11876079        11876107        CA      GA
A01     11616453        11616463        TA      TG
A01     11875367        11875368        GG      GA
A01     11667971        11667993        CA      AA
A01     11564406        11564411        TA      TG
A01     11477215        11477235        TG      CG
```

Contents of `tmp.awk`

```
{
 if (substr($4,1,1) != substr($5,1,1)) {
    print $1 "_" $2 " " substr($4,1,1) " " substr($5,1,1);
 }
 if (substr($4,2,1) != substr($5,2,1)) {
    print $1 "_" $3 " " substr($4,2,1) " " substr($5,2,1);
 }
}
```

Sample output

```
[user@server ~]$ awk -f tmp.awk tmp.txt
A01_11814111 G A
A01_11485519 G T
A01_11667971 C A
A01_11876079 C G
A01_11613258 A G
A01_11876079 C G
A01_11616463 A G
A01_11875368 G A
A01_11667971 C A
A01_11564411 A G
A01_11477215 T C
```

Bonus. In `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   set $line
   if [ ${4:0:1} != ${5:0:1} ]
   then printf "$1_$2 ${4:0:1} ${5:0:1}\n"
   fi
   if [ ${4:1:1} != ${5:1:1} ]
   then printf "$1_$3 ${4:1:1} ${5:1:1}\n"
   fi
done < tmp.txt
```

Sample output

```
A01_11814111 G A
A01_11485519 G T
A01_11667971 C A
A01_11876079 C G
A01_11613258 A G
A01_11876079 C G
A01_11616463 A G
A01_11875368 G A
A01_11667971 C A
A01_11564411 A G
A01_11477215 T C
```

Answer (score 0):

#### awk solution:

```
awk '{
    split($4$5, arr, "");
    if(arr[1] == arr[3])
        print $1 "_" $3, arr[2], arr[4];
    else
        print $1 "_" $2, arr[1], arr[3];
}' input.txt
```

#### sed solution:

```
sed -r ' 
{
    s@(\w*) *(\w*) *(\w*) *(\w)(\w) *\4(\w)$@\1_\3 \5 \6@
    s@(\w*) *(\w*) *(\w*) *(\w)(\w) *(\w)\5$@\1_\2 \4 \6@

}' input.txt
```

**Output (both the same)**

```
A01_11814111 G A
A01_11485519 G T
A01_11667971 C A
A01_11876079 C G
A01_11613258 A G
A01_11876079 C G
A01_11616463 A G
A01_11875368 G A
A01_11667971 C A
A01_11564411 A G
A01_11477215 T C
```